# Is calling someone "old school"- offensive/derogatory?

Tags: expressions, idioms, pragmatics

My colleague, a relatively young school teacher, prefers not to use e-mails.
He is digitally absent.

> During a recent teacher's meeting, while I appreciated his efforts
>   towards content development, I also called him "old school".
>   (associating a sense of pride in being Old School)
>
> I can tell, the comment has made a difference, our relation has dived
>   south.

- Is calling someone "old school"- offending/derogatory?

Comment: It's certainly got that connotation nowadays (though how many people does it take to prove a connotation?) 'Dinosaur' has a non-pejorative meaning (its main sense!), but ...

Comment: It depends on the context. It can be an insult, a compliment, or even neutral.

Comment: I get called old school all the time.  I take it as a compliment.

Comment: that's the premise which made me call him "old school".

Comment: What's most interesting to me here is the expression, "dived north"  I assume this is the same as my more usual "gone south" but I've never heard it before.

Comment: To call someone who avoids using email "old school" would not be particularly insulting in the US -- it's a reasonable description.  If instead you used the term because the individual adhered to a moral standard and refused to participate in chicanery, that would be insulting.

Comment: @Jim, it was my poor sense of direction, it remains the same as what you said.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/131688/13804

Comment: An example of a "positive" use would be in music.  "man, that DJ is kickin' it old school" would imply that the DJ knows how to play in a forgotten genre, or how to make something "classic" seem fresh.  But rarely is it positive when referring to technology.

Comment: *Anything* can have positive or negative connotations in the right tone. Sir Humphrey's use of "courageous" to mean "bad idea that will lose you the election is the go-to example.

Comment: People close-voting here for the POB reason should consider the conditions attaching (no references, no expertise shown in answers). Here, there _is_ intelligent discussion, and a reasonable vote in favour of: 'It can be taken either way'.

Comment: @MobyDisk `But rarely is it positive when referring to technology.`  Uh... not correct. I'm a sysadmin, and exclusively use "old-school" in a complimentary sense. (As does everyone else I know in the IT field.) I'm an old-school sysadmin, meaning I know what I'm doing, have copious amounts of knowledge and use the tried-and-true ways of performing my trade. If you want to pejoratively refer to someone as out-of-date regarding technology, the preferred term is "dinosaur."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest answer is: Yes. There *is* a very strong derogatory flavour often associated with the noun-as-adjective. According to this article from [The Age](http://www.theage.com.au/comment/oldschool-values-still-appeal-in-modern-world-20140608-zrzzg.html):

> To say something is "old school" has become a pejorative [usage]. It
>   implies out-of-date thinking.

This association is not *guaranteed* to be assumed by a listener or intended by a speaker, but the term should only be used with great caution, carefully thought out contextualisation.

If one includes the views of the former Google Dictionary, the situation with connotations is seen to be bipolar:

> **old school**: used, usually approvingly, to refer to someone or something that is old-fashioned or traditional.

But better safe than sorry (and I suspect that a younger audience might rather assume the pejorative nuance).

I once complimented a speaker on the way he communicated in such an acceptable, gentle (though not weak) manner. It's hard to give compliments without sounding mushy or patronising (I find). However, my 'You're an expert at hedging' wasn't exactly the best way I could have phrased it.

Comment: I think it's very much situation dependent.  In situations where it's clear that doing it the "old" way is bad, then it can be construed as derogatory.  But in situations where doing it the "old" way is considered better, more thorough, more careful, etc. then it should be taken as a compliment.  For example, when listening to vinyl and someone says, "Now, that's old school man!" I wouldn't take that as a being derogatory at all.

Comment: Yes; I've put in a mitigation. I assumed OP was asking 'Is there a possibility he's taken this as a put-down? A largish one?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that's it- he's taken my calling him "old school" as a put-down.

Answer (score 11):

It could be taken either way, or as a neutral, matter-of-fact description, depending on context:

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=old%20school):

> Anything that is from an earlier era and looked upon with high regard or respect. Can be used to refer to music, clothing, language, or anything really.
>
> Client: We have three PC's running MS-Dos 6.
> Consultant: Shi'...that's old school.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/old-school)

> Used, usually approvingly, to refer to someone or something that is old-fashioned or traditional:
>
> amenities that my parents, being of the old school, still take for granted'

[The Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/old-school)

> Old. Used when describing something you remember from a long time ago like in the 80's or early 90s.
>
> To do something in a way that is more in line with traditional technique/style rather than modern or progressive style
>
> Old fashioned, out of style, uncool. Opposite of "new school," which is hip, with it, in fashion.

Comment: MS-Dos 6 would be something `looked upon with high regard or respect.`?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Someone who lived through it might!

Comment: +1 for context sensitivity. A younger person calling an older person it, is more likely to be taken well than an older person using it on a younger person: in the latter case, it suggests sarcasm and possibly insinuates that the younger is pretentiously affecting an old-school manner. If someone is sensitive of their own technical incompetence, then even speaking of it admiringly can be seen as scornful.

Answer (score 4):

> The old school is any group of people who are
>   **[traditionalists](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/traditionalist)**: they do things the way they've been done in the past.
>
> It’s a term with **pride** woven around it.

- However, ***considering the situation***- the teacher's meeting- **the young guy did not buy your compliment.**

Answer (score 3):

When someone calls themselves "old school", it usually means something positive. It means that they consider themselves diligent, conscientious, and honest in contrast to the perceived tendency of the younger generation to avoid hard work and to find an "easy way out."
When you call somebody else "old school", the possibility of offensiveness depends on the context, specifically whether you said something positive or negative about them. Some examples - You could say: "Your handwriting is excellent-you're old school!" and that would be a compliment. Or you could say: "You don't know how to use current technology-you're old school." That would be offensive.
Some relationship advice: Why don't you tell your colleague what specifically you want him to do? So instead of telling him that "there's something wrong with him" for not using digital communication technology, tell him that "the school needs this report and that response in computer form because those are the guidelines, thanks for your understanding. We'll be happy to help if you need help with this and that software."

Answer (score 2):

At least in AE, no, it is not derogatory.  It is almost always used with a sense of admiration or appreciation.

That being said, for every phrase in the English language, there is at least one person who will find it offensive.  This person may have his own issues about being seen as old or out of touch.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Old School" is positive. Describing someone this way implies that they haven't suffered from the same degeneration as the rest of society; that they still have the values of an earlier generation.

"Old School" implies that you have retained something good that others have lost, not the other way round. Failing to adopt modern methods of communication is just rude to your colleagues. It makes them have to go to extra effort to deal with you. The fact that you have drawn attention to this is more probably the cause of your damaged relationship than the way you said it.

Answer (score 1):

Towards the end of the animated feature "The Incredibles", after Mr. Incredible, Elastigirl and Frozone have defeated the enemy's very powerful robot, two old guys (at least one was meant to represent a famous old cartoonist -- and voiced by him) have a brief conversation over what they just witnessed.  One says, "Now *that's* old school!"  The other responds "And there's no school like the old school!"  And they both chuckle.

I'd say its largely up to factors outside of the pure words.  How it's meant may be conveyed by tone of voice and facial and other expression.  Of course it's also conveyed by the milieu: in a given societal context, "old school" might always be a pejorative.  In another, it might be the opposite.

Your friend is too sensitive, which suggests a problem with self-confidence.  Not to psychoanalyze.